# Add dynamic content with URL elements

Tags: javascript, url, dynamic

I have a question and I wonder if it's possible. I want to add dynamically content into an html page, by changing the id in the URL.

I mean, for example I want to add the name of a person to a web page:

At first my page would be : [www.mypage.com/index](http://www.mypage.com/index)

```
<p> Hello <span></span> welcome to our page</p>
```

The result I want to get, is by writing this url: [www.mypage.com/index#YourName](http://www.mypage.com/index#YourName) the code updates itself to this:

```
<p> Hello <span id="YourName">YourName</span> welcome to our page</p>
```

So the id and the content of the span updates juste by modifying the URL. I don't really know how to achieve that. I wonder if I could give to my span dynamically an id by typing it on the url, and then retrieve this id and use it as a the value of the span.

Comment: Meaning when url is  www.mypage.com/index#HerName the content will be `<p> Hello <span id="HerName">HerName</span> welcome to our page</p>` ?

Comment: That's exactly what I try to achieve.

Comment: So the span `id` change with the hashTag ?

Comment: Yes! I wonder if that's possible?

Comment: Yes, check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the ID value from the url by using `window.location.hash`.

Additionally, you can watch these changes by using the `hashchange` window event.

```js
function showHash() {
  const newHash = window.location.hash.replace("#", "");
  const resultSpan = document.querySelector(".hash-value");
  
  resultSpan.id = newHash;
  resultSpan.innerHTML = newHash;
}

window.addEventListener("hashchange", showHash, false);
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", showHash);
```

```html
<body>

  <div>Current HASH in URL is: <span class="hash-value"></span></div>

  <div class="buttons">
    <a href="#hash1">hash1</a>
    <a href="#hash2">hash2</a>
    <a href="#hash3">hash3</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think I should update my question.

Comment: Did you test the snippet locally?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/wxj992

Is this what you need to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to get a current link such as:

```html
<script>
   let YourLink = window.location.href;
   let startingPoint = YourLink.indexOf('#');
   let endingPoint = YourLink.indexOf('/'); // In case if the name is not the last thing on your link
   let NameYouWant = YourLink.substring(startingPoint, endingPoint);

   // So 'NameYouWant' would be the name you need to use
</script>
```

In case you use '#' for the starting point of every name in your link, hope it's helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how can I use this to update the content of my span?

Comment: @mscmdaddcts you give id to your span like this: ```<span id='mySpan'></span>```
and then you add ```$('#mySpan')[0].innerHTML = NameYouWant;``` to your script, P.S sorry for late answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this

```
let splits = window.location.href.split("#");
let span = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].getElementsByTagName("span")[0];
span.innerText = splits[splits.length - 1];
span.id = splits[splits.length - 1];
```